# Print column using while loop in awk

Tags: bash, loops, awk, while-loop

I need to extract the values of the 2nd column from a file while the value from $1 = 2 **until** $1 = 3. As an example, from the file

```
1 | 2.158e+06
  | 2.31e+06 
  | 5.008e+06 
2 | 693000
  | 718000 
  | 725000
3 | 2.739e+06 
  | 2.852e+06 
  | 2.865e+06
  | 2.874e+06
4 | 4.033e+06
  | 4.052e+06
  | 4.059e+06
```

I would like to extract values of the 2nd column from $1=2 until $1=3

```
693000
718000 
725000
```

I tried using awk, but I have just figured out how to extract the values from $1=1 until $2=2

```
  awk -F "|" '{if ($1>1) exit; else print $2}' foo.txt
```

Output

```
2.158e+06
2.31e+06 
5.008e+06
```

I also tried this

```
awk -F "|" '{i=2; do {print $2; i++} while ($4); if ($1>i) exit}' foo.txt
```

But it gives me the whole 2nd column

```
2.158e+06
2.31e+06 
5.008e+06 
693000
718000 
725000
2.739e+06 
2.852e+06 
2.865e+06
2.874e+06
4.033e+06
```

Does anyone know how to do this using awk or other command?

Thanks

Comment: excellent first question, with small sample data, required output and ... gasp some close to working code! Keep posting and good luck.

Comment: @shellter couldn't agree more...

Comment: Col 1 always sorted?

Comment: Thank you for so many elegant answers! All of them seem to work like a charm!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A range pattern could work nicely here. The pattern `$1==2,$1==3` will start executing the action when the first column is 2 and stop when it is 3. (Since the range is inclusive we need to check that the first column is not 3 before printing the second column in this case.)

```
$ awk -F\| '$1==2,$1==3 { if ($1 != 3) print $2 }' foo.txt
693000
718000 
725000
```

Answer (score 2):

```
hzhang@dell-work ~ $ cat sample.csv 
1 | 2.158e+06
  | 2.31e+06 
  | 5.008e+06 
2 | 693000
  | 718000 
  | 725000
3 | 2.739e+06 
  | 2.852e+06 
  | 2.865e+06
  | 2.874e+06
4 | 4.033e+06
  | 4.052e+06
  | 4.059e+06
hzhang@dell-work ~ $ awk -F"|" 'BEGIN{c=0}{if($1>=3){c=0} if(c==1 ||($1>=2 && $1<3)){c = 1;print $2}}' sample.csv 
 693000
 718000 
 725000
```

I set a flag  `c`. If $1 is not between 2 and 3,  the flag set to 0, otherwise it is 1, which means we can print $2 out.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I came up with:

```
awk -F "|" '{if ($1==3) exit} /^2/,EOF {print $2}' file
```

1) `/^2/,EOF {print $2}` signifies print everything in second column up to the    *end of file*, starting with a row that begins with a **2**

2) `{if ($1==3) exit}` stops printing once the first column is a number **3**

**Output**

```
693000
718000 
725000
```

Answer (score 2):

using getline statement in awk tactically

```
awk -v FS=" [|] "  '$1=="2"{print $2;getline;while(($1==" "||$1==2)){print $2;$0="";getline>0}}' my_file
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another `awk`

```
awk -F\| '/^2$/ {f=1} /^3$/ {f=0} f {print $2+0}' file
693000
718000
725000
```

`-F\|` set field separator to `|`
`/^2/` if file start with `2`, set flag `f` to true.
`/^3/` if file start with `2`, set flag `f` to false.
`f {print $2+0}'` if flag `f` is true, print filed `2`.
`$2+0` this is used to remove space in front of number.  Remove it if it contains letters.

Comment: What about if it contains 20,21 etc ?

Comment: This would be more general `awk -F"[| ]+" '$1~/^(2|3)$/{x=!x}x{print $2}'`

Answer (score 1):

Just so you don't have to read the entire file, exit when you see a '3':

```
$ awk -F\| '/^2\s+/ {f=1} /^3\s+/ {exit} f {print $2+0}' file
693000
718000
725000
```